# Sed version extract

Tags: regex, awk, sed, grep

I am trying to extract the version number from a string. I am unable to find the exact regex to find what I need.

For eg -

```
1012-EPS-Test-OF-Something-1.3
```

I need sed to only extract `1.3` from the above line.

I have tried quite a few things until now something like but it is clearly not working out

```
sed 's/[^0-9.0-9]*//')
```

Comment: OP is using regex(as an attempted code), as well as answer are using regex, so there could be no reason to remove regex tag here IMHO. If you are going to remove regex tag here then please do mention reason in comments, thank you.

Comment: If `s` is a variable with your string: `echo "${s##*-}"`

Comment: @Cyrus if you posted that as an answer it'd get my vote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your shown samples, easiest way could be. Simply print value of shell variable into `awk` program as input and then setting field separator as `-` and printing the last field value in it.

```
echo "$string" | awk -F'-' '{print $NF}'
```

***2nd solution:*** In case you could have anything else also apart from version number in last field of your value(where `-` is field delimiter) then use `match` function of `awk`.

```
echo "$var" | 
awk -F'-' 'match($NF,/[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)*/){print substr($NF,RSTART,RLENGTH)}'
```

***3rd solution:*** Using GNU `grep` try following once. Using `\K` option for GNU `grep` here. This will match everything till `-` and then mentioning `\K` will forget OR wouldn't consider that matched value for printing and will print all further matched value(with further mentioned regex).

```
echo "$var" | grep -oP '.*-\K\d+(\.\d+)*'
```

Comment: Thank you so much I had awk working but I am not sure that the position will be the same in the future but the 3rd solution works perfect.

Comment: @Kunj, Your welcome, happy to help, cheers.

Answer (score 3):

This should work in any `grep`:

```sh
s='1012-EPS-Test-OF-Something-1.3'
grep -Eo '[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)+' <<< "$s"

1.3
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n 's/.*[^0-9.]//p' file
```

The regexp is greedy and swallows the whole line `.*` then steps back a character at a time till the first match of `[^0-9.]`, removes the front portion and prints the remainder.

Answer (score 0):

You can use string manipulation to get the last part after `-`:

```
s='1012-EPS-Test-OF-Something-1.3'
s="${s##*-}"
```

See [this online demo](https://ideone.com/KUls11):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s='1012-EPS-Test-OF-Something-1.3'
s="${s##*-}"
echo "$s"
# => 1.3
```

See [*10.1. Manipulating Strings*](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html):

> `${string##substring}`
>     Deletes longest match of *$substring* from front of *$string*.